How to execute a function after opening an Image from disk?
I have a button which calls image.open and a drop down menu which is the "image" property of an Image Texture node. For now, the user must click to open a new image and then select that image from the drop down menu.
How could I automatically set the opened image as the "image" property for the node upon opening it?

Your button should just open a file dialog on its own and after the user choosing the image do the function execution inside the operator's execute function.
See the Operator File Import operator_file_import.py template.

